# Order of output

Tags: ruby

The code below:

```
def a
  print "Function 'a' called\n"
  99
end

print "a=", a, "\n"
```

produces:

```
Function 'a' called
a=99
```

Why does `function 'a' called` show first? I expected `a=` to be shown first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you define the method `a`; nothing is printed yet.

Then, when you get to the last line, the arguments to `print` are first evaluated before that statement prints anything.  The first and last arguments are string literals.  The middle argument is a call to the method `a`, which prints `"Function 'a' called\n"` before returning 99.

Then, the `print` statement that started all this is finally ready to print now that each of its arguments has been evaluated.

Answer (score 11):

Before arguments are passed to a method, they are evaluated (so that you have values to pass). Evaluation of a call to function `a` has a side effect of printing `"function 'a' called`. That's why it is printed first.

Answer (score 3):

First, the method `a` is executed completely, including the `print "Function 'a' called\n"`. Only after the method returned `99`, the line `print "a=", a, "\n"` can be executed.

Think of it this way: The return value of `a` needs to be known before it can be printed in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
print "a=", a, "\n"
```

is processed as

```
print("a=", a(), "\n")
```

so all the parameters to the call to `print` must be evaluated before it is called. That means calling `a` first.

If the statement was to output `a=` first, before calling `a()`, it would have to consist of three separate calls to `print`.